# Словарь в телеграм боте

Tags: бот

https://pastebin.com/yDu939g4

Здравствуйте, помогите пож, что здесь не так.
Ошибок нет, просто не отправляет значение словаря в бот.
Мне нужно чтобы, бот в ответ юзера отправил количество баллов/бонусов.
Но не знаю как.
Ответ должен выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Спасибо всем.

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самостоятельным, поэтому перенесите код в вопрос и используйте форматирование для кода (в редакторе есть такая кнопка). Кроме того, поставьте теги, соответствующие языку и библиотеке бота. Токен бота уберите, чтобы бота не увели. Напишите подробнее в чем проблема. Если ошибка, то добавьте ее текст

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите вашу проблему подробнее, на какой строке ошибка, какая ошибка и т.д.